# why is my kudu DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE and SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH wwwroot?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

When I do a `git push azure develop` , I see that the DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE and SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH is wwwroot when I access it from my deploy.cmd file. Why is it not APPSETTING_SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH = d:\home\site\repository as shown in my scm / kudu site ?? How can I fix this to be d:\home\site\repository. I am trying to deploy a node.js site to azure website. I am also seeing that the IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT is set to 1.

my .deployment file just has a reference to the batch file like this:

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

Comment: Do you have either `SCM_NO_REPOSITORY` or `SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH` set in your app settings?

Comment: @ahmelsayed no I don't.